# Flutter: how to enable gestures in a web view?

Tags: webview, flutter, zooming, gestures

I would like to pinch in and out to zoom in my web view page in Flutter.
I did some researches online and I found this somewhere:

"Although pinch and zoom are built-in to WebView (Android) and UIWebView (iOS), they need to be "switched-on".
In Android, the plugin needs to call the following:

```
this.webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
this.webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); to allow pinch/zoom.
```

In iOS, the plugin needs to call the following:

```
self.webview.scalesPageToFit = YES; to allow pinch/zoom."
```

The problem is that I don't know where to put this code/I don't know how to use it. 
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: The Android part sould be implemented https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/34#issuecomment-368372251 If it doesn't work create a new issue there or better a pull request.

Answer (score 2):

Put the zoom method after webview declaration,Please refer below code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
}
```

Comment: I found that, if you enable the zoom, you will get not only these buttons to zoom https://us.123rf.com/450wm/vectora/vectora1504/vectora150400104/38423249-stock-vector-zoom-in-zoom-out-buttons-ui-element-template.jpg?ver=6
but also the gesture (pinch in and out). 
Now the question is: 
is there a way to delete those buttons in order to use only pinch in/out?