# enable pinch and zoom in webview_flutter, where to add code snippet [this.webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

wanna pinch and zoom to webview_flutter

(I know flutter_webview_plugin can do that, but I wanna stick to flutter_webview for other reasons.)

[Zoom support #34](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/34)

[Flutter: how to enable gestures in a web view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628868/flutter-how-to-enable-gestures-in-a-web-view)

[Flutter webview plugin - enable pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195972/flutter-webview-plugin-enable-pinch-zoom)

They all mentioned

> this.webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
>
> this.webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); to allow pinch/zoom.

forgive my stupidity, I can't find where to add this code snippet, please help.

Comment: Just call replace `this.webView` with your variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this repository: https://github.com/FisherWL/plugins/tree/add-zoom (thanks [FisherWL](https://github.com/FisherWL))

copy the folder **webview_flutter** located inside packages to your project root folder,

then on the pubspec.yaml reference the folder like this:

```
  webview_flutter:
    path: ./webview_flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with zoom property? This question asked two years ago and fix it with zoom property.

Also this.webView.getSettings in native library code. If you want to use, the first will write the Webview manager in java native code then call you a manager.

More than look source code library(this manager class have setSupportZoom & setBuiltInZoomControls, only just use with zoom property set the true ) [WebviewManager Source](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/flutter_webview_plugin/WebviewManager.java)

Answer (score 0):

In the webview_flutter package there is a way to zoom in or out, but I think it's not very efficient. Nevertheless, it works ✌.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:zoom_widget/zoom_widget.dart';

Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
Zoom(
maxZoomWidth: size.width * 3,
maxZoomHeight: size.height * 3,
child: WebView(
   initialUrl: myUrl),
),
```

Depending on your needs, you may modify the maximum ZoonWidth and height